# Not able to understand this piece of code. (Writing map using reduce)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was reading about javascript reduce function through MDN docs [(Link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). But I am not able to understand a piece of code in there.

Here is the code ([Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#write_map_using_reduce)):

```
if (!Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce) {
  Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce = function(callback, initialValue) {
    return this.reduce(function(mappedArray, currentValue, index, array) {
      mappedArray[index] = callback.call(initialValue, currentValue, index, array)
      return mappedArray
    }, [])
  }
}

[1, 2, , 3].mapUsingReduce(
  (currentValue, index, array) => currentValue + index + array.length
)
```

**My main question is:** In the above code what is the use of initialValue argument? Why is it calling callback with initialValue as `this` (because the first argument of `call` should be `this`)  even though `callback(currentValue, index, array)` works fine. Also, is the if statement `if (!Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce)`  necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most `Array.prototype` methods take an optional additional argument along with callback function called [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters). It's the value to use as `this` when executing the callback. `initialValue` is a bad parameter name, especially in the context of `reduce`. It could be confused for the [`initialValue` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#parameters) of `reduce`

In your case, it doesn't matter because you are using an arrow function as the callback. `this` value cannot be set. If you have a normal `function(){}`, you can make use of the `this` in it.

In the first example, a `Set` object is used as the `thisArg`. Inside the callback, check if `currentValue` is duplicate based on whether the size of `Set` stays the same when the `currentValue` is added to it.

The second example uses an object with `sum` to keep track of a cumulative sum of the array.

```js
Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce = function(callback, thisArg) {
  return this.reduce(function(mappedArray, currentValue, index, array) {
    mappedArray[index] = callback.call(thisArg, currentValue, index, array)
    return mappedArray
  }, [])
}

const repeatStatus = [1, 2, 2, 3].mapUsingReduce(function(currentValue) {
  return this.size === this.add(currentValue).size ? 'duplicate' : 'unique'
}, new Set()) // <-- this object is the "thisArg"

console.log(...repeatStatus)

const cumulativeSum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].mapUsingReduce(function(currentValue) {
  return this.sum += currentValue
}, { sum: 0 })

console.log(...cumulativeSum)
```

The condition `if (!Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce)` used to make sure the method is only created once and not overwritten again and again.

Answer (score 0):

The example should replace `initialValue` with `thisArg`(or _this, that..). Wrong naming.

With `call()` yon can use `this` context in the callback. It's not required.

Also, with `if (!Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce)` you can execute above code twice safely. It's not required, too.

Comment: Instead of `context` they should have named it `thisArg`. "Context" is an ambiguous term as in the ECMAScript specification it refers to "execution context", which has a completely different meaning. When speaking of `this` the specification uses the term "this binding".